# Find the next record in the table. After a datetime. Sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

See I have a table, its fields, I wrote below. After the query should be a one record. That in which a minimum period of time. Beginning and ending of dateend datestart. i have a tables:

broadcasting
rows: id, datestart, dateend, namecategory, page
The table broadcasting the following information:

```
'1 ', '2012-01-09 13:00:00', '2012-01-09 15:00:00 ',' News', 'N1'
'2 ', '2012-01-09 16:00:00', '2012-01-09 17:00:00 ',' News', 'N1'
'3 ', '2012-01-09 11:00:00', '2012-01-09 12:00:00 ',' News', 'N2'
'4 ', '2012-01-09 16:00:00', '2012-01-09 18:00:00 ',' News', 'N2'
```

Can I withdraw "page" in which the time between records is minimal?

After the query should show:

```
N1
```

Generally it is possible to implement such a request? While only guess that here without min () can not do.

Comment: Your question contents is confusing while your question subject seems unambiguous. Please try to clarify what you want a little bit.

Comment: He/she needs to determine on which page programs has minimal interval between them. In example provided, N1 has 1-hour interval and N2 has 4-hour interval.

Comment: '2012-01-09 15:00:00 ' minus '2012-01-09 16:00:00' 1 hour. That's according to this scheme should work query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    page
  , MIN( (SELECT next.datestart - a.dateend
          FROM TableX AS next
          WHERE next.page = a.page
            AND next.datestart >= a.dateend
            AND next.id <> a.id
          ORDER BY next.datestart ASC
          LIMIT 1
         ) 
       ) AS gap 
FROM 
    TableX AS a
GROUP BY
    page
ORDER BY 
    gap ASC
LIMIT 1
```

---

For showing all gaps, not calculating the smallest one:

```
SELECT
    page
  , ( SELECT next.datestart - a.dateend
      FROM TableX AS next
      WHERE next.page = a.page
        AND next.datestart >= a.dateend
        AND next.id <> a.id
      ORDER BY next.datestart ASC
      LIMIT 1
    ) AS gapToNextBroadcast 
FROM 
    TableX AS a
WHERE                                   --- optional for
    page = @pageToCheck                 --- one page only
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the decision. How do I add that he sought only intervals with records containing the N1?

Comment: You can add a `WHERE page = 'N1'`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  page
FROM 
  MyTable
ORDER BY 
  dateend - datestart
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: A little something. This query subtracts a record in one line. And calculates the time. But I need to calculate the gap between records.

Answer (score 0):

I don`t think that this is possible to do using only SQL... Or it is will be too complicated. May be it is better to precalculate intervals in some script and store in cache or something similar?

Comment: But what additional fields may add something?